# jQuery animate content below a .show

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a hidden extended form that is revealed when a button is clicked. The animation of the new form is working great. But not so much the content below the extended form, which jumps partly down to its new location.

How can I get the content below to get relocated smoothly all the way? And when I hide the form again, by clicking the Cancel-button, it show a flicker in the end of the animation of the Change-form-button, how come?

A demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/mNRem/6/

This is the jQuery code:

```
var duration = 400;
var formHidden = true;
$('.hidden-form').hide();
$('.change-form-button').click(function() {
  formHidden = !formHidden;
    if (formHidden) {
      $('#extend-button').hide(duration);
      $('.hidden-form').show(duration);
    } else {
      $('#extend-button').show(duration);
      $('.hidden-form').hide(duration);
    }
  return false;
});
```

And this is the html:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        Some content before form...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <form>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td><div class="hidden-form">New name</div></td>
              <td><input id="name" type="text" class>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><div id="extend-button" class="change-form-button btn btn-primary">Change form</div></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
              <td><div class="hidden-form">Address</div></td>
              <td><div class="hidden-form"><input id="address" type="text" class>&nbsp;</div></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>
                <div id="save-button" class="hidden-form btn btn-primary">Save</div>
                <div class="change-form-button hidden-form btn btn-primary">Cancel</div>
              </td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        Some content after form...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is not very easy. I suggest you create a wrapper around your form which slightly grows to a fixed size, then reduces to the actual size of it's contents. Working on a fiddle right now...

Comment: [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/mNRem/7/) but this may be not perfect and you are animating in the same form elements so it's kinf of not perfect.

Comment: [My version's](http://jsfiddle.net/r7eyr/1/) done now too. However, still has that weird jump at the end of the hiding animation... I had hoped this would remedy it. Looking at the sizes in the developer tools revealed no obvious reason for this strange behavior... sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I see that the mentioned flicker actually does not appear in Chrome, but did so in Safari. And Derija93's solution works almost great in Chrome, except for a small jump when hiding the form again (if anybody has a though on why?). Both your examples could have been the accepted answer. But I guess Derija93's example works best, maybe you could make it an "official" answer, and I will accept it? Thanks a lot guys!